# getLayoutInflater cannot resolve

Tags: android, android-studio

This code belongs my arrayadapter for custom spinner.I'm getting error of cannot resolve method on getLayoutInflater() method and I don't know why.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
    View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinneritems, parent, false);

    TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.spinneritem);
    main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);
    return mySpinner;
}
```

}

Comment: getLayoutInflater method is applicable from context object. In the adapter constructor you need to pass object of context and call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
  LayoutInflater inflater= getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

or

```
 LayoutInflater inflater= youContext.getLayoutInflater();
```

because method `getLayoutInflater()` belong to `Activity` and you must get it with `getActivity()` method or pass context into your `adapter` constructor for example :

public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Strings> someList;

    public YourAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> someList) {
        super(context, R.layout.comment_item, someList);
        **this.mContext = context;**
        this.someList = someList;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = **mContext**.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourItem, null);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

and in your `Activity`

```
YourAdapter mAdapter = new YourAdapter ( **getActivity()**,someList);
```

Comment: Sorry but still saying cannot resolve method in either way.

Answer (score 4):

***Try this one works for me.***

```
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

> cannot resolve method on getLayoutInflater()

Android **[getLayoutInflater ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/Window.html#getLayoutInflater())** retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on.

In here you are missing to set **Context**

**Don't**

```
  LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
```

**Do**

```
LayoutInflater inflater= Your_class_context.getLayoutInflater();
```